# Do you have to account for cover AC when attacking with a whip?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, cover

Let's say three combatants are in a line. The goblin is in the first square, the fighter in the second square, and the bard with a whip behind the fighter.

If the bard attacks the goblin with the whip 'over' the fighter, does the goblin get a cover bonus to it's AC?

Answer (score 11):

## YES

Per the SRD:

> **Cover**
>
> To determine whether your target has cover from your ranged attack, choose a corner of your square. If any line from this corner to any corner of the target’s square passes through a square or border that blocks line of effect or provides cover, or **through a square occupied by a creature, the target has cover (+4 to AC).**
>
> When making a melee attack against an adjacent target, your target has cover if any line from any corner of your square to the target’s square goes through a wall (including a low wall). **When making a melee attack against a target that isn’t adjacent to you (such as with a reach weapon), use the rules for determining cover from ranged attacks.**

Emphasis mine. Whip, as a reach weapon, uses ranged attack rules for cover, and ranged rules give +4 AC if there is a creature between attacker and the target.

Comment: Thank you! I read the cover rules entry, but somehow missed the second bolded sentence in your answer.

Comment: Glad to help! I remembered it only because I forgot it earlier:)